# Parse nested XML into DataFrame

Tags: python, xml, pandas, dataframe, xml-parsing

I get back a response from an API in XML form. It looks like:

```
<result_set>
    <status> ...
    </status>
    <copyright> ...
    </copyright>
    <results>
       <congress> ...
       </congress>
       <chamber> ...
       </chamber>
       <num_results> ...
       </num_results>
       <offset> ...
       </offset>
       <members>
         <member>
           <id> ... </id>
           <name> ... </name>
           ...
           ...
           ...
         </member>
         <member> ... </member>
         ...
         ... 
         ...
       </members>
    </results>
</result_set>
```

I need the data under each  tag into a pandas dataframe of the form:

```
id name ... ... ...
1  JOHN ... ... ...
2  DOE  ... ... ...
```

I have tried ElementTree, but I have failed in all attempts so far.

Comment: ElementTree is a good approach.  Show us what you've tried so far even if it's not working then we can help

Comment: Do you need the data only under `members `?

Comment: @balderman, yes. I need the data of each member.

Comment: @lazycamper OK. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Below

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<r> 
         <members>
         <member>
           <id>1</id>
           <name>jack</name>
         </member>
         <member>
           <id>5</id>
           <name>dan</name>
         </member>

       </members>
       </r>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
data = []
members = root.findall('.//member')
for member in members:
    data.append({c.tag:c.text for c in list(member)})
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df.head())
```

output

```
  id  name
0  1  jack
1  5   dan
```